# Access child constructor from base class constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given the following class hierarchy: `ChildClass` extends `ParentClass`, is it possible to access the `ChildClass` constructor function from the `ParentClass` constructor? For example:

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
    constructor()
    {
        super()
    }
}

ChildClass.prop = 'prop'

class ParentClass
{
    constructor()
    {
        if (this._child().prop == 'prop') // here
        {
            console.log("All ok");
        }
    }

    get _child()
    {
        return this.constructor;
    }
}
```

In other words, what I'm trying to do is access the child's 'static' property for verification purposes

Answer (score 5):

> is it possible to access the ChildClass constructor function from the ParentClass constructor?

Every Child is a Parent but not every Parent is a Child.

No. You can't. Even if possible with some dirty codes, don't do it. Rethink about your design. In the chain of Inheritance every Child should inherit the properties of Parent. Not the reverse.

Just think that there are 3 children and which children's props you get ? Bummer.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. And no, `this.constructor` isn't 'dirty code' but a regular way to reach static properties. It depends on the situation if it's a design mistake or not.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `this._child` instead of `this._child()`, because `child` is property accessor, not a method:

```
class ParentClass
{
    constructor()
    {
        if (this._child.prop == 'prop')
        {
            console.log("All ok");
        }
    }

    get _child()
    {
        return this.constructor;
    }
}
```

`_child` getter is redundant and misleading. Usually `this.constructor` is used directly:

```
class ParentClass
{
    constructor()
    {
        if (this.constructor.prop == 'prop')
        {
            console.log("All ok");
        }
    }
}
```

Referring to 'child' in parent class is semantically incorrect (a parent doesn't and shouldn't 'know' about its children, and `_child` can be a parent itself), but referring to `this` is not.